# Custom sorting a list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, date-sorting

I want to sort the following list with some elements as dates and some are Quarters.

```
input_ls = ['Nov-2015', 'Quarter 1, 2016', 'Jan-2016', 'Dec-2015',
           'Feb-2016', 'Quarter 4, 2015']
```

Expected output is as follows. How can I do this?

```
output_ls = ['Quarter 1, 2016', 'Feb-2016', 'Jan-2016', 'Quarter 4, 2015'
             'Dec-2015', 'Nov-2015']
```

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered. If you want to have a sorted dictionary, you need to use `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: @MaxNoe OK. My goal is to order the keys part in the dictionary. Hence I'm modifying the question as sorting a list in custom order.

Comment: Sorting a list can be done in two ways, *in place* using the `list.sort()` method, or using the built-in `sorted()` which returns a list.  Mechanisms for custom order have changed, so please specify your python version.

Comment: @cdarke Please have a look at my input and output

Comment: @Niyas: yes, I looked.  Please show the code where you tried to use either `sort` or `sorted`.  What problems are you having?  Please specify *exactly* the criteria for the order.

Comment: Do you know how to sort by a custom key yet? You'll have to write code that parses your 'dates' so they can be ordered by the `sorted()` function or `list.sort()` method.

Comment: @cdarke Some elements in the list are dates and others are 'Quarter'. I can parse dates in to datetime object and sort it. But I don't know how to sort when 'Quarter comes to consideration'.

Comment: Please explain WHY `Quarter 1, 2016` comes before `Feb 2016`, but `Quarter 4, 2015` comes before `Dec-2015`.  I have written some code for you but I can't understand the logic of your sort order.

Comment: @cdarke basically Jan, Feb, March is Quarter 1 then Apr, May, Jun is Quarter 2 and so on. First I need to display the Quarter and then the corresponding months in that quarter. Hence Quarter 1, 2016 will be displayed first, then the corresponding months. Similarly for Quarter 4, 2015.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`datetutil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
from dateutil import parser
import re
input_ls = ['Nov-2015', 'Quarter 1, 2016', 'Jan-2016', 'Dec-2015','Feb-2016', 'Quarter 4, 2015']
res = []
for x in input_ls:
    #Match x if it is having a digit followed by a comma followed by a space and followed by four digits
    qtr = re.findall('(\d),\s(\d{4})',x)
    #If match not found parse it as date by prefixing '1,' to the string
    if len(qtr) == 0:
        res.append(parse('1,' + x))
    #If matching then format it to a string format that is acceptable to the dateutil parser
    else:
        res.append(parse(str(int(qtr[0][0])*3)+'-30-'+qtr[0][1]))
#Sort the output list
out = zip(res,input_ls)
out.sort()
#Reverse it 
out.reverse()
```

And this is how the output will look like:
[image]

**Here is another way of doing using sort key probably the most pythonic way - with help from [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)**

```
from dateutil import parser
import re
input_ls = ['Nov-2015', 'Quarter 1, 2016', 'Jan-2016', 'Dec-2015','Feb-2016', 'Quarter 4, 2015']

def sort_key(x):
    qtr = re.findall('(\d),\s(\d{4})',x)
    #If match not found parse it as date by prefixing '1,' to the string
    if len(qtr) == 0:
        return parse('1,' + x)
    #If matching then format it to a string format that is acceptable to the dateutil parser
    else:
        return parse(str(int(qtr[0][0])*3)+'-30-'+qtr[0][1])

input_ls.sort(key=sort_key)
```

And this is how the output will look like:

[image]

Comment: Why not put everything in the loop body in a *sort key* rather than use an explicit `zip()` to augment?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't know how to do it, can you please show an example?

Comment: Just put the whole block in a function, `def sort_key(x):`, and use `return` instead of `res.append()`. Then use `input_ls.sort(key=sort_key)` or `sorted(input_ls, key=sort_key)`.

Comment: So your `sort_key` function is given any one of the entries in `input_ls`, and you return a value to sort by. You may want to return the *first* day of a quarter in that case however.

Answer (score 0):

#### New answer after question change :

You'll need a mapping of calendar months & quarters to numbers to suit your expected output. One example could be :

```
mapping = {'Jan':1, 'Feb':2, .. 'Quarter 1':4, .. }
```

Then iterate the list, parse each entry and map it to a number for sorting.

```
i_map = {}
for i in input_ls:
    # for 'Nov-2015' format
    i1 = i.split('-')
    if len(i1) == 1:
        # For 'Quarter 1, 2015' format
        i1 = i.split(',')

    # Now map it to a number for sorting 
    i_map[mapping[i1[0]]] = i

# Now sort i_map by key
i_map_sorted = sorted(i_map, key=lambda (k,v) : k) 

# Now you can iterate over the sorted object & print its values
```

#### Old answer before question change :

If you want a custom sorting order for a dictionary, you can use a lambda function like this

```
sorted(input_dic.items(), key=lambda (key,value) : <fn of key & value>)
```

Can you specify the logical order in pseudo code ?

To reverse the order, add `reverse=True` in the above function

If you want to sort the values only, then loop over the dictionary and sort them individually e.g.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
new_dict = OrderedDict()
for k,v in mydict.items():
    new_dict[k] = sorted(v, key=<some fn>, reverse=True)
```

If you want to sort by calendar month value (not alphabetical name), you'll need a lookup in your custom sorting function to map the month to a number e.g. {'Jan':1, 'Feb':2, ...}

P.S. The output of the `sorted` fn would be a tuple. As pointed in the comment above, use an OrderedDict if you want to keep the dict structure.

Comment: `str.split()` on a string without the delimiter will *still return one element*, the unsplit string. Your `if not i1` will never be true.

Comment: you are modifying i_map in the loop and trying to sort it. But it has only one value.

Comment: @MartijnPieters & Niyas : Thanks for pointing that out, fixed now.